# Replace values in column of a dataframe based on overlap with a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, replace

Good evening,

I have a large dataframe of 150.000 lines and 7 columns as follows

```
     ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
 XXXYYY    0    0    0    0    0    0
 XXYYXX    0    0    0    0    0    0
 XYXYXY    0    0    0    0    0    0
 YYYXXX    0    0    0    0    0    0
...
```

I also have vectors veca, vecb, vecc, vecd, vece and vecf containing subsets of the IDs in my dataframe. 
I would like to write a loop in which I assign 1 to columns based on overlapping of ID numbers between the dataframe and the vector. 
For example, if `veca <- c("XXXYYY", "XXYYXX")` then the output should be:

```
     ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
 XXXYYY    1    0    0    0    0    0
 XXYYXX    1    0    0    0    0    0
 XYXYXY    0    0    0    0    0    0
 YYYXXX    0    0    0    0    0    0
...
```

... and this I would like to repeat for all the columns.

Normally I would write something like this:

```
dataframe$cola[dataframe$ID %in% veca ] <- 1
```

I am however, having trouble writing the above in a loop. I have tried various combinations of paste and assign but so far no luck.

Later in my code I also want to remove lines of the dataframe based on a similar overlapping of ID numbers (normally written `dataframe <- dataframe[!(dataframe$ID %in% veca),])` but I assume this would be very similar to

Lastly, I should add that my platform is x86_64-w64-mingw32 and my version of R is R version 3.1.2

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#addones

lstcol <- list('cola', 'colb')
lstvec <- list(veca, vecb)

myfunc <- function(COL, VEC) {
  dataframe[[COL]][dataframe$ID %in% VEC] <<- 1
}

for(i in 1:length(lstcol)) {
  myfunc(lstcol[[i]], lstvec[[i]])
}

dataframe

#      ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
#1 XXXYYY    1    0    0    0    0    0
#2 XXYYXX    1    0    0    0    0    0
#3 XYXYXY    0    1    0    0    0    0
#4 YYYXXX    0    0    0    0    0    0

#remove lines

rowstoremove <- c('YYYXXX')
dataframe[!dataframe$ID == rowstoremove, ]

#       ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
# 1 XXXYYY    1    0    0    0    0    0
# 2 XXYYXX    1    0    0    0    0    0
# 3 XYXYXY    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

You can finish by filling out the complete `vec` and `col` lists for your full output.

Comment: Another option would be using `Map`, i.e. `myfunc <- function(v1, v2){
v1[d1$ID %in% v2] <-1;
v1}; d1[-1] <- Map(myfunc, d1[-1], lst)`  The `lst`, `d1` are from my post.

Comment: thank you! I was thinking about using `mapply` to replace that for loop. Nothing worked. I needed the function to go through the COL list and the VEC list by the ith element. So `Map` is the right one. got it

Comment: This seems to be to be an excellent solution, and one I would very much like to apply. I did make a rather silly error in my question however, the objects I thought were vectors were indeed lists. Do you think you could provide a similar solution using list objects @plafort ?
Thank you very much and sorry for the mess up.

Comment: np add one example of the lists into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new user and I can't seem to find where to edit my original question. The following is an example of how one of my lists might look like:
The list does (somewhat obviously) not contain the numbers, those indicate the row of each ID (it's a single column with many rows)

`head(example_list)

       ID

1 XXXXXX

2 YYYYYX

3 XXXYYY

4 XXYYXX

5 XXXXXY

6 XXXXYY`

Comment: that doesn't look like a list in the sense of R code. `class(example_list$ID)` gives you what result?

Comment: `class(example_list$ID)` returns `factor`. However, `is.list(example_list)` returns `TRUE`

Comment: data frames are lists in R. They are special types of lists. Just subset the data the way I did `object$column` type of format and it will act as vector for you. In your case, `example_list$ID`.

Comment: `veca <- as.character(example_list$ID)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row/column` indexing

```
lst <- mget(paste0('vec', letters[1:6]))
d2 <- stack(lst)
d1[-1][cbind(match(d2$values, d1$ID),
   match(substr(d2$ind, 4,4), substr(names(d1)[-1], 4,4)))] <- 1
d1
#      ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
#1 XXXYYY    1    0    1    0    1    1
#2 XXYYXX    1    0    0    0    0    0
#3 XYXYXY    0    1    0    1    0    1
#4 YYYXXX    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

To remove the overlapping IDs,

```
IDstoremove <- Reduce(`intersect`, lst) #in this example, none
d1[!(d1$ID %in% IDstoremove),]
```

#### data

```
d1 <- structure(list(ID = c("XXXYYY", "XXYYXX", "XYXYXY", "YYYXXX"), 
cola = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), colb = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), colc = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), cold = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cole = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), colf = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "cola", 
"colb", "colc", "cold", "cole", "colf"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

veca<-c("XXXYYY","XXYYXX")
vecb <- 'XYXYXY'
vecc <- c('XXXYYY', 'YYYXXX')
vecd <- 'XYXYXY'
vece <- 'XXXYYY'
vecf <- c('XXXYYY', 'XYXYXY')
```

Comment: great idea with the indexing. I don't use `stack` much, will research applications. +1

Comment: @plafort Thanks, I think the `match` part is not needed here (as it is ordered).  In this case, assuming the order is the same, we can set the names of the lst with 1:7, convert to numeric after `stack` and then use it as column index.

Comment: I am terribly sorry @akrun, the objects that I thought were vectors were indeed lists. So veca might be:

1   XXXYYY

2   XXYYXX

This ruins the stacking. Is there a way to get past that?

Comment: @Sigugeir Are you saying that `veca <- list('XXXYYY', 'XXYYXX')`.  In that case you can unlist it `veca <- unlist(veca); vecb <- unlist(vecb);...` and then the same code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post why it doesn't work? The code that you propose generates the correct output for me:

```
    > ## Set up the dataframe d1
    > z4<-rep(0,4) # 4 zeros
    > d1<-data.frame(ID=c("XXXYYY","XXYYXX","XYXYXY","YYYXXX"), cola=z4,colb=z4,colc=z4,cold=z4,cole=z4,colf=z4)
    > veca<-c("XXXYYY","XXYYXX")
    > d1
          ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
    1 XXXYYY    0    0    0    0    0    0
    2 XXYYXX    0    0    0    0    0    0
    3 XYXYXY    0    0    0    0    0    0
    4 YYYXXX    0    0    0    0    0    0

    > ## change cola
    > d1$cola[d1$ID %in% veca ] <- 1
    > d1
          ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
    1 XXXYYY    1    0    0    0    0    0
    2 XXYYXX    1    0    0    0    0    0
    3 XYXYXY    0    0    0    0    0    0
    4 YYYXXX    0    0    0    0    0    0

    > ## Remove lines
    > d1<-d1[!(d1$ID %in% veca),]
    > d1
          ID cola colb colc cold cole colf
    3 XYXYXY    0    0    0    0    0    0
    4 YYYXXX    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: the question asks how to loop the process for all vectors `vec[a]` and columns at once.